# form_for methos not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Hi have just started learning rails and trying to create user form using form_for method but showing me some unexpected error

Below is my code
Controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = User.new
    end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>New page</h1>

<%= form_for @user  do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

rouutes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static#index'

  get '/about', to: 'static#about'

  resources :user
end
```

and it showing me error
[image]

Can you please correct me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us your `routes.rb` file

Comment: @s3tjan Question updated with routes file content

Answer (score 1):

Change your:
  `resources :user` to  `resources :users` 
and in controller 
  `class UserController < ApplicationController` to `class UsersController < ApplicationController`
by convention, rails expects the controller name to be plural. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your routes as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static#index'
  get '/about', to: 'static#about'

  resources :users   # plural
end
```

You use singular mostly:

> When look up without referencing an ID. For example, you would like /profile to always show the profile of the currently logged in user.

[Rails Routing from the Outside In 2.5 Singular Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

Also be aware that singular resources map to plural controllers.